# Sentence interpretation

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

I have been accused of a lack of reading comprehension in the following statement:
*Irgun later on became part of the "Jewish authorities", specifically the IDF* by a self-professed wordsmith.
To me, it basically states that Irgun became the IDF and I have been taken to task for that interpretation. However, I can see no alternative.

Comment: As it stands, I'd agree with your interpretation of that fragment, but context would help here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether "specifically the IDF" relates to "Irgun ... became" or to "the Jewish authorities" (i.e. he became a part of the authorities, specifically that part known as the IDF). The second reading is just as intuitive as the first, I would say.

An alternative could be:

> Irgun later on became part of the "Jewish authorities" (specifically
>   that part known as the IDF)

but I wouldn't say that is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read it as "Irgun became part of the "Jewish authorities", and Irgun specifically became **part of** the IDF."

A quick look on Google leads to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irgun) where I find:

> The Irgun militants were then fully integrated with the IDF and not kept in separate units.

I think an interpretation as you suggest is possible, but not necessarily the only one.